# Display message when checkbox is checked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I know it should be simple, but I couldn't find a way to do it and I have a feeling that is simple but I am stuck. I am trying to display a message every time a checkbox is checked. I have the code below but I can only display the message for the first checkbox. I am just starting with Javascript.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Second checkbox is checked</p>

Checkbox3: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Third checkbox is checked</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same id is rule violation give class.

Comment: make the checkbox id unique.

Answer (score 1):

`id` must be unique, You can pass `id` of both `checkbox` and `p` as parameter to function as follows,

```js
function myFunction(id,pid) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(id);
    var text = document.getElementById(pid);
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1"  onclick="myFunction(this.id,'text1')">

<p id="text1" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2"  onclick="myFunction(this.id,'text2')">

<p id="text2" style="display:none">Second checkbox is checked</p>

Checkbox3: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3"  onclick="myFunction(this.id,'text3')">

<p id="text3" style="display:none">Third checkbox is checked</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not going to go on about the importance of [why #IDs need to be unique](https://www.deque.com/blog/unique-id-attributes-matter/) and how that hobbles the expected behavior of the checkboxes. There are 2 demos:

**Demo 1** uses JavaScript which is IMO overkill for a simple task.

1. For event handling, try to avoid using [on-event attribute event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers):

   `<div` **onclick="func();"**`></div>`

   Try **[`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** instead, follow the links for details.
2. [**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) is used in **Demo 1** so only the added `<form>` element is used as the eventListener instead of multiple checkboxes.
3. An alternate way of referencing form controls (ex. `input`, `textarea`, etc) is by using the [**HTMLFormControlsCollection** API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection). Wrapping inputs into an actual `<form>` tag and giving them `#id` and/or `[name]` attributes we can use a simple and short syntax. In this demo it really isn't needed but here's an example of a conventional way vs. **event delegation/HTMLFCC**:

   **Normal way:**

   ```
    var chxs = document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]');
    for (let i = 0; i < chxs.length; i++) {
       chxs[i].addEventListener('change', message);
    }
   ```

   **Event Delegation/HTMLFormControlsCollection**

   ```
    var form = document.forms.formID;

    form.addEventListener('change', message);
   ```

   ---

**Demo 2** uses CSS only.

- Using two pseudo-classes:

  - [**`:checked`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) gives us two states to change styles like `display:none/block`.
  - `+` **[Adjacent Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)** allows us fine grain control of elements that immediately follow the checkbox (as well as additional siblings and descendant nodes if needed).

---

**Details commented in Demos**

### Demo 1

```js
// Reference the form - see HTMLFormControlsCollection
var chxGrp = document.forms.checkGroup;

/* Register the change event to form. 
|| Call message() function when a change event happens on or 
|| within the form.
|| A change event occurs when the user enters data (*input*) 
|| within a form control like an input (*focus*) then clicks onto
|| another (*unfocus*).
|| change event is different than most of the events because it
|| involves multple steps from the user, but it is very effective 
|| for form controls.
*/
chxGrp.addEventListener('change', message);

/* The Event Object is passed through, you might've seen it as 
|| "e" or "evt". How it's labelled doesn't matter because Event
|| Object is always available when you deal with the DOM.
*/
function message(event) {
  
  // if the node clicked is a checkbox see if it's...
  if (event.target.type === 'checkbox') {
  
    // ... checked then...
    if (event.target.checked) {
    
      // ...find the node that follows it (i.e. <b>)...
      event.target.nextElementSibling.className = "message";
    } else {
      /* Otherwise remove any class on it. (there's a more modern
      || method: classList that can be used instead)
      */
      event.target.nextElementSibling.className = "";
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
b {
  display: none
}

label {
  display: table
}

[type=checkbox] {
  display: table-cell;
}

.message {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Wrapped the checkboxes with a <form> giving us opportunities: 
HTMLFormControlsCollection API for specialized referencing and
Event Delegation allowing us to use a single eventListener for an
unlimited amount of event.targets (clicked, changed, inputed, 
etc. buttons, links, etc.)-->
  <form id='checkGroup'>

    <p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked: </p>

    <label>Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox">
  <b>Checkbox is CHECKED!</b>
  </label><br>

    <label>Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox">
  <b>Second checkbox is checked</b>
  </label><br>

    <label>Checkbox 3: <input type="checkbox">
  <b>Third checkbox is checked</b>
  </label><br>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

### Demo 2 - CSS Only

```css
/* Default state of message tag */

b {
  display: none
}


/* Using label as a container that acts like a table */

label {
  display: table
}


/* Checkboxes are normally set as a component that sits inline
with their siblings. Acting as a table-cell does that and has
additional advantages as well. 
When the checkbox is :checked...
The adjacent sibling + <b> behaves as a table-cell as well,
thereby being shown/hidden by the corresponding checkbox being
toggled.
*/

[type=checkbox],
[type=checkbox]:checked + b {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Layout has been slightly re-arranged to take advantage of 
styling combonations and tag behavior -->
  <p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked: </p>

  <label>Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox">
  <b>Checkbox is CHECKED!</b>
  </label><br>

  <label>Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox">
  <b>Second checkbox is checked</b>
  </label><br>

  <label>Checkbox 3: <input type="checkbox">
  <b>Third checkbox is checked</b>
  </label><br>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the same ID. Try changing two ID's to have either a number on the end (myCheck 1 or myCheck2), or change it to something else completely. Here's my suggestion:

```js
function myFunction(idCheck, idText) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(idCheck);
    var text = document.getElementById(idText);
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction('myCheck', 'text')">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1"  onclick="myFunction('myCheck1', 'text1')">

<p id="text1" style="display:none">Second checkbox is checked</p>

Checkbox3: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2"  onclick="myFunction('myCheck2', 'text2')">

<p id="text2" style="display:none">Third checkbox is checked</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have input type checkbox with uniq id.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="uniq_id" />
```

Then in script, call your function

```
$("#uniq_id").click( function(){
  if( $(this).is(':checked') ){ 
     //call your function here
     myFunction(this);  
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

id need to be unique. Pass the `id` through the `onclick` handler using `this.id`

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById(id);
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked === true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Second checkbox is checked</p>

Checkbox3: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Third checkbox is checked</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since id is unique identifier your function always selects first checkbox.

```
document.getElementById("myCheck");
```

You need to modify it to smth. like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>
    Checkbox:
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_1" onclick="myFunction(event)">
    <p id="text_check_1" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

    Checkbox2:
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_2" onclick="myFunction(event)">
    <p id="text_check_2" style="display:none">Second checkbox is checked</p>

    Checkbox3:
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_3" onclick="myFunction(event)">
    <p id="text_check_3" style="display:none">Third checkbox is checked</p>

    <script>
        function myFunction(event) {
            var checkBox = event.target,
                id = checkBox.id,
                text = document.getElementById("text_" + id);
            if (checkBox.checked == true) {
                text.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                text.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have to use different IDs, also you don't need several `p` elements for that and lastly to avoid unnecessary queries, you could pass the clicked element to the function since you are calling it via the `onclick` attr.

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
    var checkBox = elem;
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1];
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        p.innerHTML = "Checkbox <b>" + checkBox.id + "</b> is CHECKED!"
        p.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       p.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1"  onclick="myFunction(this)">

<p class="text" style="display:none"></p>

Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2"  onclick="myFunction(this)">

Checkbox3: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3"  onclick="myFunction(this)">

</body>
</html>
```

HIH

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript or jquery at all - this can be achieved using CSS alone - using the direct sibling selector and the :checked pseudo selector you can set the display or visibility property on the next p.

You did have multiple id's so that needs to be corrected - but CSS is all you need to toggle the next p after the checked checkbox.

```css
p{display: none}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + p {display: block}
```

```html
<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1">
<p>First Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2">

<p>Second checkbox is checked</p>

Checkbox3: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2">

<p>Third checkbox is checked</p>
```